# MySQL Connectivity dyld fix

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, macos, macos-catalina

So, I am getting into Laravel, the PHP framework, anyhow, when I go to use PHP, I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mysql
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I've tried reinstalling OpenSSL,  but it's the 1.1.1d version, but when i go to the Cellar, it's 1.0.1f. I've also tried uninstalling and removing, but it said it was dependent on some packages. I don't know what to do from here, and these errors that I've never gotten before is really slowing down my web development.

Comment: This is why I dislike `homebrew`; you could try using `MacPorts` instead perhaps.

Comment: Well, I was told to use homebrew to install Valet & Laravel and stuff like that. But I can't even install Valet because I get the same error there too!